# Invalidating a graphic

Tags: c#, gdi+

I have a got a graphic object of a rectangle this is created when the button on the picturebox is clicked but if the form is moved off the screen the graphic dissapears as well as the whole form it just goes white i have tried to invalidate the picturebox but this stops the button from working can anyone help me keep the object on the form using the invalidate method i know theres a way but i can't seem to grasp it

```
  private void squareButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Declaring a new graphics object has been assigned null
            Graphics objGraphics = null;
            // This will create the picture graphics to be drawn in the picturebox
            objGraphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            // This will redraw the picture box with a fill chosen after the systemcolors
            objGraphics.Clear(SystemColors.ControlDark);
            // This will draw the rectangle with a red pen 10,10 represent position and 50,50 reprsent the width and height 
            objGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 10, 10, 50, 50);
            // This will draw the rectangle
            objGraphics.Dispose();
invalidate(PictureBox1);

// This is not redrawing the graphic it just shows a blank form

        }
```

Comment: Don't use CreateGraphics.  Use the Paint event of the PictureBox then just call `PictureBox1.Invalidate();` to tell windows to call the paint method of that control.

Comment: But paint us an event handler how can i use it almost like a method

Comment: Using the Paint event handler can be a bit raw on new programmers.  You don't have to, you can create a simple canvas.  Assign a new Bitmap to the PictureBox.Image property in the constructor and draw to that bitmap with Graphics.FromImage().  Call Invalidate() to get it painted to the screen.

Comment: Thanks i am trying to do this now following what you said and it seems to be the exact same i am a beginner could you maybe help by putting the code  on here for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics objGraphics = null;
    // This will create the picture graphics to be drawn in the picturebox
    objGraphics = e.Graphics;
    // This will redraw the picture box with a fill chosen after the systemcolors
    objGraphics.Clear(SystemColors.ControlDark);
    // This will draw the rectangle with a red pen 10,10 represent position and 50,50 reprsent the width and height 
    objGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 10, 10, 50, 50);
    // This will draw the rectangle
    //objGrphics.Dispose();

}
```

Comment: Could i not somehow use invalidate in a button click or will i have to use it in a paint even on the picturebox

Comment: just put pictureBox1.Invalidate(); in your button click event.